# Uncaught exception - debugging techniques (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, gdb, mach-o

I have encountered a curious scenario in which the following unlikely code:

```
try{
  throw Core::ValueError();
}
catch (Core::Error &e){
  ...
}
```

(ValueError inherits from Error inherits from std::exception)

results in the exception being caught if compiled into an executable, but not if compiled into a particular shared library.

And so my questions:

1. What debugging tools and/or techniques can I use to peek inside the black-box that is the exception handling process? Can I step through it with gdb?
2. Is there any information I could pull out of the Mach-o headers that would tell me anything about the catchablility (if you will) of certain exceptions by certain catch clauses? In particular, can I look say at the "gcc_except_tab" section with its lovely LSDA's, or the symbols table, or another part, and deduce any problem with symbol visibility or other issue relevant to catching exceptions?

I did find an online source that claimed a solution using a chicken, seven rat tails and a particle accelerator, but I figured I'd try StackOverflow first and leave the black  magic as a last resort.

(I'm running i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 on OSX 10.6.7)

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  I tried compiling that code as a shared library and the exception was caught as expected.

Comment: Yes, I got the same result for a simple attempt at reconstruction (exception is caught). So now I have a simple example that works, a complicated one that doesn't, but not the tools to compare them. I started hacking parts off of the original code in order to minimize it while still replicating the problem, but I'm still dealing with a black box - I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing a temporary object so you should `catch( Core::Error const& e )`.